# why is outlook removing the spaces between my images

Tags: html, image, outlook, spaces

I have 4 small images lined up horizontally as shown below

```
        <span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color: gray">
        <a href="image link"><img src="image source"></a>
        <a href="image link"><img src="image source"></a>
        <a href="image link"><img src="image source"></a>
        <a href="image link"><img src="image source"></a><br /> </span>
```

when i run the code, browsers diplay these for images with the right space between them, but if i run the code using outlook the test it, the images do not have the spacing between them. I understand this is an outlook problem but is there a way to solve these issue, i have tried adding padding style and margin stil to each image but that does not help. How can i get around this problem to add spaces between these images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook tends to ignore most of CSS and almost anything you put into a "style" attribute, so your most reliable option here is to insert &nbsp; (non-breaking space) entities between the images.

Comment: yeah this worked, thanks although it added a bit of extra space between the images now when i run it in the browsers

Comment: You'll want to adjust your CSS accordingly, keeping in mind that it'll only take effect in the browsers, while only the &nbsp; entities will have any effect in Outlook. Glad to be of help!